# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ForeignKey'

Tags: django, django-models

I am a beginner in Django.

I need columns showing only the type_of_due_date that exists in the selected country.

In "class InputType" I tried to use limit_choices_to and Q function, but see a mistake like

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ForeignKey'#

Please, help. What I did wrong?

My models:

```py
class InputVatDueDate(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name='Country', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True,
                                blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(_('date'), default=datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('input vat due date')
        verbose_name_plural = _('input vats due date')
        unique_together = (('country', 'date'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country.name


class TypeOfVatDueDate(models.Model):
    vat_due_date = models.ForeignKey(InputVatDueDate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type_of_due_date = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=enum_to_choice(TypeDueDates))
    date_of_start = models.IntegerField(_('day of start date'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type_of_due_date

class InputType(models.Model):
    vat_due_company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyVatDueDate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.ForeignKey(InputVatDueDate, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    type_of_due_date = models.ForeignKey(TypeOfVatDueDate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=Q(vat_due_date_id=country), )
```

Comment: Where is the code for  `TypeDueDates`?

Comment: In one of your IntegerField you are passing a ForeignKey when saving he data, that may be the problem i guess!

Comment: class TypeDueDates(enum.Enum):
    germany_monthly = 'germany monthly'
    germany_quarterly = 'germany quarterly'
    france_monthly = 'france monthly'
    france_quarterly = 'france quarterly'

    @classmethod
    def translation(cls):
        return {
            cls.germany_monthly: 'Germany monthly ',
            cls.germany_quarterly: 'Germany quarterly',
            cls.france_monthly: 'France monthly',
            cls.france_quarterly: 'France quarterly',

        }

Comment: Try `limit_choices_to=Q(vat_due_date=F('country'))`. However, I'm not sure this will work, as `F('country')` might be executed on the related model instead of the model itself. Otherwise, I only see as way to do this in the form, as Daniel Heppner suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is here:

```
class InputType(models.Model):
    ...
    type_of_due_date = models.ForeignKey(TypeOfVatDueDate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=Q(vat_due_date_id=country), )
```

My understanding is that you want to limit the choice to `TypeOfVatDueDate` instances where the `vat_due_date` is the same value as the `country`

In this scope, the variable `country` is the `ForeignKey` field of the model *class*, not the value of the field `country` of the current model *instance*.

I'm not aware of implement what you are trying to achieve on a model level. You will have to do that at some other place, e.g. in a custom ModelForm:

```
class InputTypeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        # Restrict queryset if country is set
        if self.instance and self.instance.country:
            self.fields['type_of_due_date'].queryset = TypeOfVatDueDate.objects.filter(vat_due_date=country)

    class Meta:
        model = InputType
```